# How to have a list or an array of string in my model of ASP.NET MVC_CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first

I want to use `Code-first` Database.This is my Model of asp MVC

`Model`:

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Qu { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ans { get; set; }
    public virtual List<string> KeyWords { get; set; }
}
```

Each object of `Question` must have a list of `KeyWords`.
Is it a correct way or it will be better if I have a model of `KeyWords` then here create a list of object keyword?

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: What is your problem with having `List<string>`?

Comment: How it would be in table of data base?

Comment: Assuming `Keywords` contains the possible answers for a `Question`, then your table (say QuestionAnswers) needs to contain fields for the `QuestionId` and the value

Comment: as I guess it need's Keyword Object. thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: I assume what you mean is that its not creating your table? (EF does not support collections of primitive types) so creating a `KeyWords` object is the way to solve that

Comment: really thank you for all these great helps and knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think if you want to store the data in a database you would need to normalize the code.  I would do it this way:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Qu { get; set; }
    public string Ans { get; set; }
    public virtual List<string> KeyWords { get; set; }
 }
public class Keyword
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("question")]
    public int QuestionID {get;set;}
    public string keyword {get;set;}
    public virtual Question question {get;set;}
 }
public QuestionModel :DBContext
 {
    public virtual DBSet<Question> Questions {get;set;}
    public virtual DBSEt<Keywords> Keyword {get;set:}
 }
```

I use ICollection<> instead of List for the virtual collections but I'm not sure it matters.